# Is it common to describe "Be going to" form as Simple Future?

Tags: meaning, will-vs-going-to

"Be going to" form is called Simple Future in some English Grammar websites and books.

> Simple Future has two different forms in English: "will" and "be going to" [English Page](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplefuture.html)

> The Simple Future Tense has two different forms in English, *will* and *be going to*. [Contextual English](https://books.google.ae/books?id=UtzLKD4KNGAC)

I had discussion with a very good English user (I don't know if she is a native speaker or not) about this form. and she said
she had never heard of "Be going to"  described as Simple Future.

So, Is it common to describe "Be going to" form as Simple Future?

Comment: I think yes. I consider it as a form of future simple when it's **interchangeable** with _will_. Because, There are some cases that it's not.

Comment: I will be going to the opera next week. I will be going to the dentist soon.

Comment: @Willow Rex it's worth mentioning that _be going to_ in your examples is not a form of the modal _be going to_ but _future continuous_ (will+be+verb+ing) and it's the main verb of your sentence that the simple form of it is _go_.

Comment: @Yuri, thanks, I suck at grammar  -- that helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is tricky because you need to remember to conjugate the verb. Technically, it is "**to be** going to". But yes, they are mostly interchangeable. For example, the following two sentences have the same meaning:

> I am going to have my car fixed tomorrow.
>
> I will have my car fixed tomorrow.

But it is incorrect to say:

> I be going to have my car fixed tomorrow.

In this example, the verb *to be* has not been conjugated.